# Closing instance

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, instance, add-in

I am calling Excel objects from MS Access and I do not manage to close the instance!

One would believe that the workbooks are closed because we cannot see them anymore but in task Manager --> Processes I still have EXCEL.EXE*32 running...

This is what I have:

```
Dim xlApp as Excel.Application
Dim wbks as Workbooks


    Set xlApp = GetObject("", "Excel.Application")
    Set wbks = xlApp.Workbooks
    wbks.Open "C:\blp\api\Office Tools\BloombergUI.xla"
    wbks("BloombergUI.xla").RunAutoMacros (xlAutoOpen)

    wbks.Add
    xlApp.Visible = True
```

...performs actions...

```
xlApp.Workbooks(1).SaveAs FileName:=strFullPath, FileFormat:=xlCSV

    xlApp.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    xlApp.Workbooks("BbgDivData.csv").Close SaveChanges:=True
    wbks("BloombergUI.xla").Close

    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Any idea why it is still there? I suspect the Add-in to mess things up!

Comment: is wbks.Add maybe creating a second Excel instance?  Try explicitly creating a new Excel object and making a new workbook in it for your actions, then call .quit on both.

Comment: I'm inclined to go with your suspicions, though it might be worth steppign through your code in debug and looking at what happens in task manager re excel instances at each step.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove Excel task from Task manager after running from Access using VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512868/remove-excel-task-from-task-manager-after-running-from-access-using-vba)

Answer (score 1):

You never explicitly set the *collection* of workbooks to nothing, you just call close from one member. I would try adding:

```
Set wbks = Nothing
```

after the `Close` and before the `Quit`.