# Excel File Locked After Export

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am having some issues with the below piece of code.  The data exports fine from access to excel, however, when I go to view the excel file it says its locked for editing.  Does anyone know why?

```
Public Sub ExportFiles()

Dim X As Object
Dim Y As Object
Dim XL As Object
Dim rs As Recordset

Set X = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set Y = X.Workbooks.Open("\\POISE\Data\LCS\DomGroup\ICE NMW Performance and DQ\Tasking MI\2014-15\Production Pack Template\OFFICIAL SENSITIVE Tasking Team Production Pack.xlsx")
Set XL = Y.Sheets("Tasking Records")
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("ALL")

XL.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

Y.SaveAs "\\POISE\Data\LCS\DomGroup\ICE NMW Performance and DQ\Tasking MI\2014-15\Production Pack Output\" & "Tasking " & "Week " & Format(FiscalWeek, "w") & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx"

X.Visible = False

Set X = Nothing
Set Y = Nothing
Set XL = Nothing
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not closing the excel application properly. You need to close the workbook and quit excel before setting the objects to nothing.

For more information see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23350327/3198973) to [Remove Excel Task from Task Manager after running vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512868/remove-excel-task-from-task-manager-after-running-from-access-using-vba/23350327#23350327).

```
Public Sub ExportFiles()

Dim X As Object
Dim Y As Object
Dim XL As Object
Dim rs As Recordset

    Set X = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set Y = X.Workbooks.Open("\\POISE\Data\LCS\DomGroup\ICE NMW Performance and DQ\Tasking MI\2014-15\Production Pack Template\OFFICIAL SENSITIVE Tasking Team Production Pack.xlsx")
    Set XL = Y.Sheets("Tasking Records")
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("ALL")

    XL.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

    Y.SaveAs "\\POISE\Data\LCS\DomGroup\ICE NMW Performance and DQ\Tasking MI\2014-15\Production Pack Output\" & "Tasking " & "Week " & Format(FiscalWeek, "w") & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx"

    X.Visible = False

    ' remove objects in reverse order to creation
    Set XL = Nothing
    ' close workbook before quitting excel
    Y.Close
    Set Y = Nothing
    'close excel before setting it to nothing
    X.Quit
    Set X = Nothing


    rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  If I wanted to add in a 2nd workbook in another file path, would it be best to repeat the code or is there another way?

Comment: @AHughes You would want to create a subroutine that takes the filepath of the workbook you want to copy and the destination range as a parameter. Take a look at this tutorial over @ [CPearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/byrefbyval.aspx). If you have trouble refactoring your code, post another question and we'll help you out.